# Valgrind: Invalid read of size 4, out-of-bound segfault error

Tags: c++, multithreading, valgrind, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm having a segfault error in my multi-thread project.
This project is a cyclic program that has to run continuously, It is architected to have TASKS that are in turn composed of one or more OPERATIONS.

Running Valgrind I receive memory leak and out-of-bound (Invalid read of size 4) warnings.

Valgrind LOG:

```
==30039== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30039== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30039== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30039== Command: ./sisCAT
==30039== 
DebugLog: ++++++++++++++ Inicio de Execucao ++++++++++++++++++++++ 
DebugLog: iniciando ciclo do controller

DebugLog: 3 
==30039== Invalid read of size 4
==30039==    at 0x8081714: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:52)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039==    by 0x807F78C: SISCAT::Controller::Run() (Controller.h:57)
==30039==    by 0x807F71D: SISCAT::SisCAT::run() (SisCAT.cpp:27)
==30039==    by 0x804C8F8: main (boia.cpp:73)
==30039==  Address 0x7355274 is 20 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==30039==    at 0x48D1CFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30039==    by 0x807D1B2: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*, unsigned int) (new_allocator.h:98)
==30039==    by 0x807C3B9: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_put_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:373)
==30039==    by 0x807B08B: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:395)
==30039==    by 0x807A17F: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:1076)
==30039==    by 0x8079564: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~_Rb_tree() (in /home/lioc/Siscat/sisCAT/Debug/sisCAT)
==30039==    by 0x8078FD6: std::map<std::string, SISCAT::Task*, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~map() (stl_map.h:88)
==30039==    by 0x80816D0: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:40)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039== 
==30039== Invalid read of size 4
==30039==    at 0x4984BE5: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==30039==    by 0x80817A9: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:63)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039==    by 0x807F78C: SISCAT::Controller::Run() (Controller.h:57)
==30039==    by 0x807F71D: SISCAT::SisCAT::run() (SisCAT.cpp:27)
==30039==    by 0x804C8F8: main (boia.cpp:73)
==30039==  Address 0x735526c is 12 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==30039==    at 0x48D1CFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30039==    by 0x807D1B2: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*, unsigned int) (new_allocator.h:98)
==30039==    by 0x807C3B9: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_put_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:373)
==30039==    by 0x807B08B: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:395)
==30039==    by 0x807A17F: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:1076)
==30039==    by 0x8079564: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~_Rb_tree() (in /home/lioc/Siscat/sisCAT/Debug/sisCAT)
==30039==    by 0x8078FD6: std::map<std::string, SISCAT::Task*, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~map() (stl_map.h:88)
==30039==    by 0x80816D0: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:40)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039== 
==30039== Invalid read of size 4
==30039==    at 0x4984BFB: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==30039==    by 0x80817A9: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:63)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039==    by 0x807F78C: SISCAT::Controller::Run() (Controller.h:57)
==30039==    by 0x807F71D: SISCAT::SisCAT::run() (SisCAT.cpp:27)
==30039==    by 0x804C8F8: main (boia.cpp:73)
==30039==  Address 0x7355264 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==30039==    at 0x48D1CFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30039==    by 0x807D1B2: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*, unsigned int) (new_allocator.h:98)
==30039==    by 0x807C3B9: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_put_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:373)
==30039==    by 0x807B08B: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:395)
==30039==    by 0x807A17F: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:1076)
==30039==    by 0x8079564: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~_Rb_tree() (in /home/lioc/Siscat/sisCAT/Debug/sisCAT)
==30039==    by 0x8078FD6: std::map<std::string, SISCAT::Task*, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~map() (stl_map.h:88)
==30039==    by 0x80816D0: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:40)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039== 
==30039== Invalid read of size 4
==30039==    at 0x4984C00: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==30039==    by 0x80817A9: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:63)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039==    by 0x807F78C: SISCAT::Controller::Run() (Controller.h:57)
==30039==    by 0x807F71D: SISCAT::SisCAT::run() (SisCAT.cpp:27)
==30039==    by 0x804C8F8: main (boia.cpp:73)
==30039==  Address 0x73551dc is 12 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==30039==    at 0x48D1CFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30039==    by 0x807D1B2: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*, unsigned int) (new_allocator.h:98)
==30039==    by 0x807C3B9: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_put_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:373)
==30039==    by 0x807B08B: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:395)
==30039==    by 0x807A17F: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:1076)
==30039==    by 0x8079564: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~_Rb_tree() (in /home/lioc/Siscat/sisCAT/Debug/sisCAT)
==30039==    by 0x8078FD6: std::map<std::string, SISCAT::Task*, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~map() (stl_map.h:88)
==30039==    by 0x80816D0: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:40)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039== 
==30039== Invalid read of size 4
==30039==    at 0x4984BF2: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==30039==    by 0x80817A9: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:63)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039==    by 0x807F78C: SISCAT::Controller::Run() (Controller.h:57)
==30039==    by 0x807F71D: SISCAT::SisCAT::run() (SisCAT.cpp:27)
==30039==    by 0x804C8F8: main (boia.cpp:73)
==30039==  Address 0x7355220 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==30039==    at 0x48D1CFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30039==    by 0x807D1B2: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*, unsigned int) (new_allocator.h:98)
==30039==    by 0x807C3B9: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_put_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:373)
==30039==    by 0x807B08B: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:395)
==30039==    by 0x807A17F: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:1076)
==30039==    by 0x807A15F: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:1074)
==30039==    by 0x8079564: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~_Rb_tree() (in /home/lioc/Siscat/sisCAT/Debug/sisCAT)
==30039==    by 0x8078FD6: std::map<std::string, SISCAT::Task*, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~map() (stl_map.h:88)
==30039==    by 0x80816D0: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:40)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039== 
==30039== Invalid read of size 4
==30039==    at 0x4984C12: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==30039==    by 0x80817A9: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:63)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039==    by 0x807F78C: SISCAT::Controller::Run() (Controller.h:57)
==30039==    by 0x807F71D: SISCAT::SisCAT::run() (SisCAT.cpp:27)
==30039==    by 0x804C8F8: main (boia.cpp:73)
==30039==  Address 0x73551d4 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==30039==    at 0x48D1CFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30039==    by 0x807D1B2: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*, unsigned int) (new_allocator.h:98)
==30039==    by 0x807C3B9: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_put_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:373)
==30039==    by 0x807B08B: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:395)
==30039==    by 0x807A17F: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:1076)
==30039==    by 0x8079564: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~_Rb_tree() (in /home/lioc/Siscat/sisCAT/Debug/sisCAT)
==30039==    by 0x8078FD6: std::map<std::string, SISCAT::Task*, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~map() (stl_map.h:88)
==30039==    by 0x80816D0: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:40)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039== 
==30039== Invalid read of size 4
==30039==    at 0x4984C1A: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==30039==    by 0x80817A9: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:63)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039==    by 0x807F78C: SISCAT::Controller::Run() (Controller.h:57)
==30039==    by 0x807F71D: SISCAT::SisCAT::run() (SisCAT.cpp:27)
==30039==    by 0x804C8F8: main (boia.cpp:73)
==30039==  Address 0x73551dc is 12 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==30039==    at 0x48D1CFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30039==    by 0x807D1B2: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*, unsigned int) (new_allocator.h:98)
==30039==    by 0x807C3B9: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_put_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:373)
==30039==    by 0x807B08B: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:395)
==30039==    by 0x807A17F: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >*) (stl_tree.h:1076)
==30039==    by 0x8079564: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~_Rb_tree() (in /home/lioc/Siscat/sisCAT/Debug/sisCAT)
==30039==    by 0x8078FD6: std::map<std::string, SISCAT::Task*, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, SISCAT::Task*> > >::~map() (stl_map.h:88)
==30039==    by 0x80816D0: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:40)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039== 
==30039== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==30039==    at 0x8081E99: SISCAT::Task::GetTickExecution() (Task.h:121)
==30039==    by 0x808171E: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:52)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039==    by 0x807F78C: SISCAT::Controller::Run() (Controller.h:57)
==30039==    by 0x807F71D: SISCAT::SisCAT::run() (SisCAT.cpp:27)
==30039==    by 0x804C8F8: main (boia.cpp:73)
==30039== 
==30039== Invalid read of size 4
==30039==    at 0x8081E99: SISCAT::Task::GetTickExecution() (Task.h:121)
==30039==    by 0x808171E: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:52)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039==    by 0x807F78C: SISCAT::Controller::Run() (Controller.h:57)
==30039==    by 0x807F71D: SISCAT::SisCAT::run() (SisCAT.cpp:27)
==30039==    by 0x804C8F8: main (boia.cpp:73)
==30039==  Address 0x13 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==30039== 
==30039== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==30039==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x13
==30039==    at 0x8081E99: SISCAT::Task::GetTickExecution() (Task.h:121)
==30039==    by 0x808171E: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:52)
==30039==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30039==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30039==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30039==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)
==30039==    by 0x807F78C: SISCAT::Controller::Run() (Controller.h:57)
==30039==    by 0x807F71D: SISCAT::SisCAT::run() (SisCAT.cpp:27)
==30039==    by 0x804C8F8: main (boia.cpp:73)
==30039==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==30039==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==30039==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==30039==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==30039==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==30039== 
==30039== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30039==     in use at exit: 10,856 bytes in 183 blocks
==30039==   total heap usage: 237 allocs, 54 frees, 14,287 bytes allocated
==30039== 
==30039== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30039==    definitely lost: 4,164 bytes in 2 blocks
==30039==    indirectly lost: 53 bytes in 2 blocks
==30039==      possibly lost: 2,427 bytes in 93 blocks
==30039==    still reachable: 4,212 bytes in 86 blocks
==30039==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30039== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==30039== 
==30039== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30039== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==30039== ERROR SUMMARY: 15 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

Parts of the functions and class involved in this report are shown below:

```
RETURN::Return_t TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(uint32_t tick,
        std::vector<Task*>& Tasks)
{
    Tasks.clear();
    if (GetTasks().empty())
        return RETURN::ERROR_UPDATING_TASK;
    Task* task;
    std::map<TaskID, Task*>::iterator iter = GetTasks().begin();
    while (iter != GetTasks().end())
    {
        if ( iter->second->GetTickExecution()== tick) **// Line: 52**
        {
            task = iter->second;
            if(task->CanExecute())
            {
            Tasks.push_back(task);
            }
        }
        iter++;                                       **// Line: 63**
    }
    return RETURN::OK;
}

uint32_t Task::GetTickExecution()
    {
        return m_tickExecution;
    }
```

This is the constructor of Task Class, where TaskID is a string type:

```
Task(TaskID name, uint32_t m_tickOffSet, uint32_t m_tickInterval,
            uint32_t m_executionsPerCycle, TaskPriority::TaskPriority_t m_prio,
            std::map<OperationID, Operation*> m_registeredOperations) :
        m_name(name), m_tickOffSet(m_tickOffSet),
                m_tickInterval(m_tickInterval),
                m_executionsPerCycle(m_executionsPerCycle), m_prio(m_prio),
                m_registeredOperations(m_registeredOperations)
```

The method where the error is reported is just a Get method, who returns a unsigned int variable.

Comment: If you suspect that the multi-threading may be responsible, run the program through `valgrind --tool=helgrind`. Your program has a multitude of memory errors, every single of which constitutes undefined behaviour and may be responsible for all other. You'll have to eliminate every single one of them, preferrably in chronological order.

Comment: @mic_e Running helgrind tool:

    [code]Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
    ==30119==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x547C20AA
    ==30119==    at 0x8078F65: SISCAT::Task::CanExecute() (Task.h:104)
    ==30119==    by 0x8081774: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:58)...[code]

Comment: In my experience, valgrind is not very useful for debugging segfaults. It should be used periodically to check whether the program is still working correctly, but once you've got segfaults, you should use gdb instead. @lfelipem: So helgrind didn't find any errors? Well that's a relief.

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is your question?

It would really help if you posted file names and line numbers with your code so people can match your code with the line numbers from the valgrind output.

This

```
==30039== Invalid read of size 4
==30039==    at 0x8081714: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:52)
```

probably means you're accessing a null pointer, or an unitialized pointer, in line number 52, and this

```
==30039== Invalid read of size 4
==30039==    at 0x4984BE5: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==30039==    by 0x80817A9: SISCAT::TaskCycle::GetTasksByTick(unsigned int, std::vector<SISCAT::Task*, std::allocator<SISCAT::Task*> >&) (TaskCycle.cpp:63)
```

hints very much at you passing a null pointer to `std::_Rb_tree_increment`. But as we can't see which are your line number 52 and 63 in TaskCycle.cpp, we can't help much with that.

If i were you, i'd either use a debugger, or add something like `printf("xxx=%p\n", xxx)` to all line numbers that are reported by valgrind (replace xxx with all pointers that are used on those lines) so you can see which ones seem to be wrong.

Comment: I edited the code with the lines you mentioned, I wasn´t able to number all lines.

Comment: When I try to print the pointer:
==30250== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==30250==    at 0x6FEBC70: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==30250==    by 0x6FF2EFE: printf (printf.c:35)
==30250==    by 0x80783B3: SISCAT::Controller::ExecuteCycle() (Controller.cpp:183)
==30250==    by 0x8078244: SISCAT::Controller::ClockCycle() (Controller.cpp:156)
==30250==    by 0x80781D5: SISCAT::Controller::StartClock() (Controller.cpp:146)
==30250==    by 0x8077B54: SISCAT::Controller::Initialize() (Controller.cpp:129)...

Comment: Then very likely something is wrong with your `iter`. Run gdb, put a breakpoint at line 52, and when you reach the breakpoint, `print iter`, `print *iter`, `print iter->second` until you notice something. You don't check if GetTasks().begin() returns NULL, is there any possibility of it NOT returning a valid iterator?

Comment: `task.begin()` returns a map of Tasks that had been initialized  in the start of the program and doesn't change it value never.
The segfault happens after a random number of program cycle.